# How to create Folder in Docusign SOAP through php API?

Tags: php, api, soap, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign eSignature SOAP API Through PHP and configured it on a test domain. I am able to create envelopes through API But Now I want to create a folder through API so that I can move any envelope to in a folder. Basically I want, Once the document is fully executed, it will be routed via DocuSign connect to a folder which aligns with the name of the user. Anyone help me out that is it possible?

Comment: Please follow the stack overflow guidelines: [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, why not use the REST API? we have an SDK for that for PHP, but not for SOAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the eSignature REST API calls that you'd use. I don't have info on DocuSign SOAP and I highly recommend that you use the eSignature REST API. You can look in the SOAP docs to find the equivalent calls, if they exist.

1. The envelope is sent
2. After the envelope completes, your app will receive a webhook notification via DocuSign Connect.
3. Your app uses the [Folders:list](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/list) call to see if the target folder exists or not. You might want to cache the results of this call.
4. If the folder doesn't exist, ask a human to create it using the DocuSign web tool. At this time, an API call to create folders programmatically is not available. I'm checking to find out the details and will update this answer.
5. Use the API call [Folders:moveEnvelopes](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Folders/Folders/moveEnvelopes) to move the envelope to the folder

Comment: Thanks, Larry, is there any way to generate the auth token in PHP for DocuSign rest APIs?

Comment: Yes, see the [PHP code examples](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php). If you have questions, please open a new StackOverflow question. And thank you for the check!

Comment: How can we download an document of envelopes list showing in table and on click on view button. I am using rest PHP apis to get envelopes list.

Comment: @VishalHira --  Please ask as a new question. Thank you.